# Chrome extension, Permission to allow site access ONLY on click

Tags: google-chrome-extension

What's the manifest permission to allow access to all webpage data, but only on click?

In the extension manager this is the option that appears as

```
Allow this extension to read and change all your data on websites you visit
   - On click
```

As an example, the Pinterest extension asks for full read/change access, but you have the option to change that to "on click" in the extension manager. I'd like "on click" to be the initial permission request.

I've looked at the permissions here https://chrome-apps-doc2.appspot.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html

I know I can request permission to access all webpage data, all the time, with

```
  "permissions": ["*://*"],
```

Comment: Replace `"*://*"` with `"activeTab"`, [more info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) and see also [optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `cookies`?

permissions: ['cookies'],
origins: ['https://dummydomain.com/*']